# Refactor Swift code with a closure

Tags: swift, closures, refactoring

I want to refactor this Swift code with a closure syntax

```
var station: Station!
var allStations = [Station]()
var favoriteStationIds = [Int]()

for favoriteStationId in favoriteStationIds {
    for station in allStations {
        if station.stationId == favoriteStationId {
            station.isFavorite = true
            continue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You posted the same question before and deleted it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46975231/swift-refactoring-closures – You should *improve* the question instead if it is unclear.

Comment: What do you want the closure to control?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach`, which have a trailing closure syntax instead of normal `for ... in` loops.

Moreover, you don't need to manually iterate through both arrays, you can use `index(where:)`, that accepts a closure to find the station with the specified id as `favoriteStationId`.

```
favoriteStationIds.forEach{ id in
    allStations[allStations.index(where: {$0.stationId == id})!].isFavorite = true
}
```

Bear in mind that above piece of code assumes all elements in `favoriteStationIds` are valid ids that are present in `allStations` (if this is not the case, use optional binding for the index instead of force unwrapping).